# Spring multiple application contexts vs single application context in an ear

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have inherited an app which is packaged as ear file that has inside

```
 - ear :
        -APP-INF/lib (persitence.jar - hibernate+spring ... etc)
        -war (web-services)
        -jar (mdb)
        -jar (mdb)
```

As I studied the app noticed that each module has inside the jar creates it's own Spring application context that is loaded on runtime.

It works ok but it would not be better to have only one application context ? 
 I wonder what are the benefits and drawback which this structure compared to the one where it is only an single application context used ?

To be more clear on runtime there are 3 application context roots loaded.It is not only that there are more application context files

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all: are you sure it isn't the same application context everywhere ? have you tested this ?

if they are all seperate:
the advantage is that those application contexts are shielded from eachother, which you could call loose coupling, which is a good thing; one can't influence the other, it keeps things clearer for the programmer.
the disadvantage is, it might be harder to access one application context from the other, but you can always find a way around this.

Comment: for example persistence layer is used in all 3 modules,but loaded in 3 app contexts.I don't; say it's not ok...just want to understand if having a single app context might bring some advantages

Comment: See what you are calling an advantage for single application context will be only at the time when your server starts and loads the application. After that it won't be benifited. But to maintain it is the key factor to consider. :-)

Comment: i have a background of j2me ... i was very carefull with what it is in 1 MB of memory :)

Answer (score 3):

If the application very large then the application context of different modules is easy to manage and it doesn't create any overhead. At the time when application is up all the context xml files will be combined.

And I will also prefer to maintain separate application context files for separate set of configurations eg. security, datasource, aop etc. should be placed in separate context files.

When the application is small then you can go for single application context file for whole application. Otherwise different application context for different modules is easy to manage in case when you need to do some changes in any one of them. If you combine all of them then it will be very difficult to do any changes in that.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Few points against single application-context file that I can think of:

1. One file will get huge and it will be maintenance nightmare.
2. Developers of each component will modify,update same file can lead to errors.
3. Changes in one component will lead to changes in one centralized file, again may lead to issues.
4. It gives every component developer "Separation of Concern", they don't have to see, know others work while carrying out there task.

Comment: I agree to have multiple files ...but i mean on runtime there are loaded 3 application contexts roots...! Splitting them only into multiple file of course ..cause it is easy to maintain...

Comment: at runtime it doesnt matter, spring will read and maintain configuration. Easy to Maintain is a very vital factor, 80% of SDLC goes in maintenance :)

Comment: for example both mdb's load their own app context that import the persistence layer context.True that it needs to be easy to maintain but was thinking if there might be some performance drawback to this.(nowdays it might not be cause there is plenty of memory ...but back when there was only 256 MB i was very careful on any extra class loaded in the memory)

Comment: True memory now is quite in abundance but what they load is a single persistence-context.xml, Spring will maintain only one file

Comment: for this case in memory there will be 3 root application contexts loaded...isolated from each other .i read there might be configured parent application context and hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this thread which seeking a solution for multi-tenant application. Most articles are just about datasource (Spring HotSwapable datasource targets) etc but what you have is a separate context at the war level.

This gives me another idea of bundling my application in a way that makes it multi-tenant. 
If the wars are skinny just to inject special runtimes and provide additional context path qualifies this may work for a large multi-tenant application. Common classes will be loaded at the EAR level and application contexts per war. I guess this should be ok for small number of tenants.